# SystemOutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, optimization, memory-management

I have around 60,000 image URLs and I'm downloading those images using multiple instances of webclient to download those images. But while downloading images it is giving SystemOutOfMemory Exception after around 15000 images. So how do I optimize webclient so it doesn't give this exception.

My code looks something like this:

```
if (!File.Exists(download_image_path))
{
wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(imgURL, download_image_path);
wc.Dispose();
}
```

And it is running in a loop.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Make sure you use the Dispose method on all disposable objects, close all file pointers and re-use allocated memory, or clean it up. Allocating memory in .Net is not a common practice though. You could use the 'using' statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some urls at a time and send it to another function or i suggest you to use another application instead, and when those images are downloaded completely then close that application, and start another application and pass another batch of urls as command line arguments, will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object Pool](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool) design pattern.

Instead of using 60000 instances of webclient (which looks from your response), use 10/15/100 whatever is optimal. Also keep is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Download one image at a time? That would be the easiest thing, if speed wasn't a concern.

Comment: speed is a concern. because there are around 60,000 images and it will take forever if i download images one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Timer Control that runs for every 1 Sec
2. Place you code inside the timer.
3. Create a counter: File_inDownload, and
       increment that in the timer. The timer should also check
       File_inDownload <100 to process the download
4. Handle the eventDownloadFileCompleted of the object wc
5. In that event reduce the counter File_inDownload by 1.